# How to convert a Trig file to a Turtle file so that i can upload it in Sesame?

Tags: sesame, turtle-rdf

```
{
    ex:repository ex:createdBy ex:repOwner; ex:title “Rep_1”.

}
ex:books 
{
    ex:book_1 a ex:Science; ex:size “100”; ex:title “Science book 1”.
    ex:book_2 a ex:Science; ex:size “1000”; ex:title “Science book 2”. 
    ex:book_3 a ex:Fantasy; ex:size “100”; ex:title “Fantasy book 1”.
}
```

Comment: IActually you just have to format it well in Trig format as Sesame supports Trig format

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted. Can you try and edit your question so it's a bit more clear what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to convert a TriG file to Turtle to upload it to Sesame, as Sesame supports the TriG format.

Moreover, conversion from TriG to Turtle *loses data*: TriG is a format that can record *quads*, so you can put several named graphs in one file, while Turtle only records triples. If you convert TriG to Turtle, you will remove all the named graph information.

Having said all that, conversion from one format to another is simple in Sesame:

```java
// writing to System.out as an example, change to a fileoutputstream to write to file
RDFWriter turtleWriter = Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, System.out);
RDFParser trigParser = Rio.createParser(RDFFormat.TRIG);

// link the parser with the writer
trigParser.setRDFHandler(turtleWriter);

File trigFile = new File("/path/to/file.trig");

trigParser.parse(new FileInputStream(trigFile), trigFile.getAbsolutePath());
```